# I am trying to write a sample user define function that will plot, but having issues

Tags: python, function, plot, user-defined

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def linear(a,b):
    return a*x+b
    plt.plot(x,linear(a,b))
    plt.show()

linear(2,4)
```

It just gives me the output `[6,8,10,12,14,16]` but not a plot. I cannot see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `return` before plot.Change your code to something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def linear(a,b):
    return a*x+b   
plt.plot(x,linear(2,4))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up shivsn. I wanted the user to be able to specify what the values of a and b are whenever they need. Which is why I did not pre-specify the values of a and b at first. If I put return after plot, it returns an error message.